# identifier 'sqlBean' resolved to null

Tags: java, class, jsf, xhtml

I'm currently working on an sql Class for JSF website. But I've got this annoying error while trying to access my class :

```
action="#{sqlBean.createAccount}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'sqlBean' resolved to null
```

Here is the code :

### Java class:

```
package com.tutorial;

import java.sql.*;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;

@ManagedBean(eager = true)
@RequestScoped

public class SqlBean {

    Connection  connec;
    Statement   flux;
    ResultSet   res;

    SqlBean()
    {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connec = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/epiMarket", "root", "seN?/g0u");
            flux = connec.createStatement();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.print("imposible to connect sql");
        }
    }

    ResultSet command(String cmd)
    {
        try {
            res = flux.executeQuery(cmd);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return res;
    }

    public String   createAccount()
    {
        try {
            flux.executeQuery("insert into epi_user values('', #{registerBean.name}, #{registerBean.surname}, '', #{registerBean.date}, #{registerBean.phone}, #{registerBean.login}, #registerBean.password)");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return ("Register");
    }
}
```

here is where i access it :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/templates/BasicTemplate.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">
    <div id="formulaire">
    <h:form>
        <h:panelGrid columns="6">
        <h:outputText value="Name"></h:outputText>
        <h:inputText value="#{registerBean.name}"></h:inputText>
        <h:outputText value="Surname"></h:outputText>
        <h:inputText value="#{registerBean.surname}"></h:inputText>
        <h:outputText value="Birth (format : dd/mm/yyyy)"></h:outputText>
        <h:inputText value="#{registerBean.date}"></h:inputText>
        <h:outputText value="Login"></h:outputText>
        <h:inputText value="#{registerBean.login}"></h:inputText>
        <h:outputText value="Password"></h:outputText>
        <h:inputSecret value="#{registerBean.password}"></h:inputSecret>
        <h:outputText value="retype password"></h:outputText>
        <h:inputSecret value="#{registerBean.passwordVerif}"></h:inputSecret>
        <h:commandButton value="Register" action="#{sqlBean.createAccount}"></h:commandButton>
    </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
    </div>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
</html>
```

for me, it's sqlBean which is not instantiate but I don't understand why.

Ok, add a `Public` before `SqlBean()` and now have a `java.lang.NullPointerException`

Here the stacktrace :

```
exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:321)
cause mère

javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:98)
    com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:98)
    javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:311)
    javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:781)
    javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1246)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:77)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:114)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:308)
cause mère

java.lang.NullPointerException
    com.tutorial.SqlBean.createAccount(SqlBean.java:44)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
    org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:278)
    org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:274)
    com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:102)
    javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:84)
    com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:98)
    javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:311)
    javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:781)
    javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1246)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:77)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:114)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:308)
```

Comment: Have you tried having a `public` constructor for the bean?

Comment: I've just do it.
The error has now change to :

`Etat HTTP 500 -java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: Please edit your post with the stacktrace if you can't figure out where the `NullPointerException` comes from. Also, what's the purpose of this site? If your answer is anything but "fooling around", please consult a [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/) before continuing.

Comment: the purpose of this site is not to fooling around...
It's a project for a market WebSite.

Comment: `flux.executeQuery` is line 44? I suggest you step back a bit and take a solid Java tutorial, then work through the tutorial link I posted earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for your Exception is most likely that your

```
flux = connec.createStatement();
```

wasn't executed. You'll find out by removing that `try-catch` block from the class' constructor. Reasons for that I can only speculate on - need to deploy the required mysql/jdbc jars perhaps?

Comment: ok, add the connection to db in createAccount function.

 
I havn't more error while launching the site, but I'm now not able to find the driver :/

 `imposible to createAccountjava.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/epiMarket`

Comment: @user3206541 Yeah, so I guessed correctly. You need the mysql driver jar. It's called Connector/J by Oracle now.

Comment: Thanks.
Succefully add the driver, but still have the same error.
Don't understand why..
Ive followed the setup instruction in oracle website, but don't work